# Gradle Not Resolving Maven Repo on localhost

Tags: maven, localhost, gradle, archiva

I have setup an [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/) instance on my localhost using the default configuration. I have tried several different Gradle configs to resolve to the archiva instance, but none seem to work.

1. using mavenRepo
2. maven
3. using Ivy and only specifying the artifact pattern (which worked when I used Ivy)

**build.gradle**

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'

    repositories {
        mavenRepo url: 'http://localhost:8080/archiva', artifactUrls: [
            'http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal',
            'http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/snapshot'
        ]
        maven { url 'http://localhost:8080/archiva' }
        ivy {
            artifactPattern 'http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal/[organisation]/[artifact]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
    }
}

dependsOnChildren()
```

I didn't think it was pertinent post any/all the subproject gradle files, but if you think it is necessary I can.

Is there something I'm missing here? Does gradle treat localhost urls differently than non-localhost (because the `mavenCentral` dependencies are being resolved)? What do I have to do to get Gradle to resolve to a local instance of a Maven repo?

**EDIT:** @Peter Niederwieser

```
:/> gradle build
> Loading > Resolving dependencies ':projects:project-plugin-framework:classpat
:projects:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:projects:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:projects:classes UP-TO-DATE
:projects:jar UP-TO-DATE
:projects:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:projects:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:projects:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:projects:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:projects:test UP-TO-DATE
:projects:check UP-TO-DATE
:projects:build UP-TO-DATE
:projects:project-plugin-framework:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:projects:project-plugin-framework:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:projects:project-plugin-framework:classes UP-TO-DATE
:projects:project-plugin-framework:jar UP-TO-DATE
:projects:project:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:projects:project:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:projects:project:classes UP-TO-DATE
:projects:project:jar UP-TO-DATE
:projects:project:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:projects:project:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:projects:project:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:projects:project:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Building > :projects:project:test > Resolving dependencies ':projects:mag
:projects:project:test

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':projects:project:tes
tRuntime'.
> Could not find group:jspf, module:jspf.core, version:1.0.2.
  Required by:
      Project.projects:project:0.0.1
      Project.projects:project:0.0.1 > Project.projects:project-pl
ugin-framework:0.0.1
> Could not find any version that matches group:erichschroeter, module:applib, v
ersion:latest.integration.
  Required by:
      Project.projects:project:0.0.1
      Project.projects:project:0.0.1 > Project.projects:project-pl
ugin-framework:0.0.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.61 secs
```

Comment: `maven { url 'http://localhost:8080/archiva' }` should work just fine, if that's the correct URL. (Please remove `mavenRepo` before you try.) What exact output do you get? Does `-s` or `-d` provide any insight? Which Gradle version/OS?

Comment: The debug info gives me a `ModuleVersionNotFoundException` for both of the unresolved dependencies, which I think is expected given the failure. I'm using Gradle 1.0-milestone-8 on Windows XP 32bit.

Comment: Where is this coming from? `Could not find any version that matches group:erichschroeter, module:applib, version:latest.integration` In particular, `latest.integration` is an Ivy concept, not a Maven one. In general, I recommend to start with the simplest possible single-project build, and take it from there. Is the URL the correct root URL of the Archiva Maven repo? Can you open `http://localhost:8080/archiva/jspf/jspf.core/1.0.2/` in the browser? (PS: I can't find such a module in Maven Central.)

Comment: The `group: erichschroeter` and `group: jspf` are groups I've setup on the localhost repo (they do not exist in mavenCentral). There is a WebDAV URL in the archiva settings which is `http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal`, and I've tried using that, but still get the same result.

Comment: Can you open the URL I gave in the browser? Does it show a .jar and a .pom? Where does `latest.integration` come from? Do you specify it somewhere in the build script? There's something wrong with this, and I don't think it would work with Maven either.

Comment: The URL you gave me does not exist, however `http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal/jspf/jspf.core/1.0.2/` does exist and contains the .jar and maven-metadata.xml. `latest.integration` comes from a sub-project `build.gradle` file where I specify a dependency `compile group: 'erichschroeter', name: 'applib', version: 'latest.integration'`. How do you specify the latest version of a dependency in gradle?

Comment: In that case you have to set the repository URL to `http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal/`. How you specify the latest integration version depends on the repo type. For a Maven repo it's `SNAPSHOT`. Of course the publisher of the module has to get it right too. The best place to get assistance for solving such problems (to which no clear-cut answer exists) is http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8024/discussion-between-e-rich-and-peter-niederwieser)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue had to deal with Gradle's cache and my initial upload of the artifacts to the [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/) repo.

When you upload artifacts in Archiva you are given a choice to generate a Maven 2 POM, and I did not do that. As a result when Gradle went to resolve the dependencies in the Archiva repo, it didn't find the POMs that I assume it was looking for and thus couldn't resolve the dependencies.

The issue was solved by deleting the `.gradle/caches` directory and simply calling `build` to start from scratch.